# Regex for cleaning Google Alert URL

Tags: php, regex

Looking for a Regex to remove everything before and including q= and after and including &ct form the following URL.

http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://www-possible-spam-link-com/foo-bar-foo-bar-foo-bar-foo-1-ea-from-foo.html&ct=ga&cad=:s7:f1:v0:d2:i2:lt:e0:p0:t1289126539:&cd=bar&usg=foo

Comment: can you give example of the output you're expecting

Comment: Is this the exact same question that was deleted yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.match(r'http://.*?q=([^&]*).*?', url).group(1)
'http://www.foo.com/bar-foo-bar-foo-bar-foo-bar-1-ea-from-foo.html'
```

You will also probably also need to decode the url in case it has any escaped entities such as & or %20. This is language-dependent though.

In PHP

```
preg_match('/^http:\\/\\/.*?q=([^&]*)/', $url, $matches);
print($matches[1]);
```

Comment: the expected output is http://www.my-sample-domain.com/buy-cheap-inner-traditions-addiction-free-naturally-1-ea-from-herbalremedies.html

Comment: yes, this is the same questions as yesterday, i didn't register yesterday, and now i can't find it...

Comment: @marcog, thanks for your answer, I tested it at gskinner.com and http://.*?q=([^&]*).*? returns http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&amp;q=http://www.discountproductshop.com/buy-cheap-inner-traditions-addiction-free-naturally-1-ea-from-herbalremedies.html

Comment: I need it to return http://www.my-sample-domain.com/buy-cheap-inner-traditions-addiction-free-naturally-1-ea-from-herbalremedies.html

Comment: Can you give the input url it's faling on?

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://www-possible-spam-link-com/foo-bar-foo-bar-foo-bar-foo-1-ea-from-foo.html&ct=ga&cad=:s7:f1:v0:d2:i2:lt:e0:p0:t1289126539:&cd=bar&usg=foo

Comment: How can that return (domain name removed).com? It's not even in that url.

Comment: I just realized that StackOverflow changed my URL to a Possible Spam Link, and replaces the elements in my URL to bar-foo-bar etc..

Comment: @user525314 that was user edits; people here are a bit paranoid about possible spam links... It would have been better to use something like example.com

Comment: Okay, now that I see the original url in the edits I tested and it works as expected. It returns http://<domain-stripped>.com/buy-cheap-inner-traditions-addiction-free-naturally-1-ea-from-herbalremedies.html

Comment: Thanks. We're working in PHP and we're trying to translate your expression to the PHP preg_match regex dialect. What is the r before the expression?

Comment: thanks @marcog, but the PHP regex provided outputs this www.google.com/url?sa=X&amp;q=http://www.discountproductshop.com/buy-cheap-inner-traditions-addiction-free-naturally-1-ea-from-herbalremedies.html it still needs to strip out this part www.google.com/url?sa=X&amp;q=

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you're reading $matches[1] and not $matches[0]? I'm using php5 - if you're on another version, that might make a difference.

Comment: to make matters even more complex, the expression's not run directly in PHP, but it's put in user-accessible field that gets run into PHP at run-time... in other words, I can't use the array structure... i've using only /^http:\/\/.*?q=([^&]*)/ but i realize from what you're saying that this is not enough... I need to do it in one statement.. thx –

Comment: Ooh, I don't know my PHP well enough to help you there. I see your problem though.

Comment: @marcog, see David's answer/suggestion about backnames and tell me what you think...

Answer (score 1):

Marco, can't he use backnames (named groups)?

You can specify backnames for groups in the standard regex dialect: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

This section says:

> Python's sub() function allows you to
>   reference a named group as \1 or \g.
>   This does not work in PHP. In PHP, you
>   can use double-quoted string
>   interpolation with the $regs parameter
>   you pass ed to
>   pcre_match():$regs['name'].

So this is your original:

/^http:\/\/.?q=([^&])/

This may work:

/^http:\/\/.?q=(\g:[^&])/

Does that make sense?

Comment: Named groups are for reference within the regex / replacement. This isn't going to help here. The problem OP faces is that he needs a regex he can pass to preg_match that matches the part he wants and only that. What he'd need is something to match-but-not-match the ^http:\/\/.?q= part, if that makes sense?